# Indefinite article used with people's names preceded by an adjective

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct and why?
This story is about a fifteen-year-old Samantha who likes animals. 
This story is about fifteen-year-old Samantha who likes animals.

Comment: You would say '...a fifteen-year-old girl who...', but as you have named your subject you don't need the article.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few options here. They are all correct, but they have nuanced differences.

---

> 1. This story is about fifteen-year-old Samantha, who likes animals.

**What does this sentence tell us?**

- The story is from Samantha's past, when she was 15.
- Fifteen-year-old Samantha (always) likes animals.

**When should you use this phrasing?**

When fifteen-year-old Samantha has always loved animals, i.e. there was never a time when Samantha was 15 years old and did not like animals.

---

> 2. This story is about a fifteen-year-old Samantha who likes animals.
> 3. This story is about fifteen-year-old Samantha who likes animals.

*Note: the below explanation focuses on example phrase 2, but the same principle applies to example phrase 3. It is the **absence of the comma** that makes all the difference here. Whether you include the indefinite article or not doesn't really change the meaning.*

**What does this sentence tell us?**

- The story is about Samantha's past, when she was 15 **and liked animals**.

**Why is this different from the first sentence?**

The second sentence implies that "who likes animals" make a meaningful distinction. It implies that there are two different fifteen-year-old Samanthas, one who likes animals and one who does not like animals.

(See below for an explanation using a different example).

**When should you use this phrasing?**

If fifteen-year-old Samantha did not always like animals.
Suppose that during the first half of the year in which she is 15, Samantha **hates** animals. But then, something happened, and she suddenly **loves** animals for the second half of the year.

It would then be correct to say:

> When I met you in the first half of the year, you were a fifteen-year-old Samantha who hates animals.
>   But when I ran into you in the second half of the year, you were a fifteen-year-old Samantha who loves animals.

---

**Consider the following examples**:

> This is a story about my brother, who is a doctor.

You can infer from this that I only have one brother, who also happens to be a doctor. The fact that he is a doctor is *tangential* information.

> This is a story about my brother who is a doctor.

You can infer from this that I probably have more than one brother, but I am now specifically talking about *the brother who is also a doctor*. The fact that he is a doctor is not just tangential information, it is used **to specify which of my brothers I am talking about**, which implies that there is more than one person who I could refer to when saying "my brother". If I only have one brother, then there's no need to further specify that he is a doctor and the information becomes tangential.

Comment: I disagree that the sentence implies the past. Out of context, it could equally well mean that Samantha is fifteen now.

Comment: @KateBunting: Yes and no. It's not impossible, but the fact that the speaker **specifies** "fifteen-year-old" very much **implies** that Samantha currently isn't 15 years old (logically speaking, if the story is a true story, that means that Samantha must invariably be **older** than 15). We would need to evaluate why the speaker feels the need to mention this information about Samantha (both her age and the fact that she likes animals at age 15), but I doubt that this distinction is meaningful within the scope of the OP's question.